# Drawing Dynamic Gradients in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm working on an art app and I want to be able to draw a gradient as a color. For example, if I keep drawing in a straight line or in circles, I want the gradient to repeat itself over and over. Right now the gradient is isolated to one side of the screen when I draw, but I would like to be able to draw with the gradient anywhere.

I have included the drawing function and color variable for reference.

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

JS

```
 window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

    let painting = false;

    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 170, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop("0", "magenta");
    gradient.addColorStop("0.5", "blue");
    gradient.addColorStop("1.0", "red");

    function windowSize() {
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    }
    function startPosition(e) {
        painting = true;
        draw(e);
    }
    function finishedPosition() {
        painting = false;
        ctx.beginPath();
    }
    function draw(e) {
        if(!painting) return;
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;

        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', finishedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', finishedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw);
    window.addEventListener('resize', windowSize);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you are trying to make a `repeating-linear-gradient` pattern.

It's supported in css, but not yet in the canvas gradient.

If all what you want to archive is a drawing like in your example, I will suggest you to do th following:

- add a css gradient as a background and cover all unused space in white.
- cover all the space in white
- set the `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';` (so it will clean the drawing instead of draw)

Like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';

    let painting = false;

    function windowSize() {
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    }
    function startPosition(e) {
        painting = true;
        draw(e);
    }
    function finishedPosition() {
        painting = false;
        ctx.beginPath();
    }
    function draw(e) {
        if(!painting) return;
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";

        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', finishedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', finishedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw);
    window.addEventListener('resize', windowSize);

});
```

```css
canvas {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, magenta, blue, red, magenta) repeat-x;
  background-size: 50px 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Also, you can use different (single) color at each event, instead of use gradient, and change the hue over time.

It will produce very different result. not sure what you like more..

Will be looking like that:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let colorIdx = 0;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

    let painting = false;

    function getColor() {
        colorIdx += 5;
        return `hsl(${colorIdx}, 100%, 50%)`;
    }

    function windowSize() {
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    }
    function startPosition(e) {
        painting = true;
        draw(e);
    }
    function finishedPosition() {
        painting = false;
        ctx.beginPath();
    }
    function draw(e) {
        if(!painting) return;
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.strokeStyle = getColor();

        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', finishedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', finishedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw);
    window.addEventListener('resize', windowSize);

});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Repeated gradient on 2D canvas

There are several ways to repeat a gradient. However they are all somewhat involved and will have some limitations and problems.

### 2 methods

- The simplest is to manually repeat the color stops (see example) but suffers from floating point error
- Use a pattern  to repeat a gradient. Render a single repeat gradient to an offscreen  canvas and use that canvas as a pattern, setting the pattern repeat appropriately. You will also have to align the gradient to the offscreen canvas axis and then set the pattern transform to match the orientation of the desired pattern.

### Repeating color stops

The following function creates a gradient and adds a function to it that will create repeated color stops.

```
function RepeatingGradient(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, repeats) {
    const dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(x1, y1, x1 + dx * repeats, y1 + dy * repeats);
    return Object.assign(gradient, {
        addRepeatColorStop(pos, color) {
            var i = 0;
            const step = 1 / repeats;
            const offset = pos / repeats;
            while (i < repeats) { 
               const p = (i++) * step + offset;
               // Rounding error may cause exception so check that p is not greater than 1
               gradient.addColorStop(p > 1 ? 1 : p, color) 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

#### Usage

`RepeatingLinearGradient(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, repeats)` It needs a 2D context `ctx`, then the standard linear gradient arguments, `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` and then the number of repeats `repeats`.

The repeats extend the area of the gradient. Thus if the positioning arguments are `0,0,0,10` and the repeat is 10 then the gradient will cover the area `0,0,0,100`

You add repeating color stops using the new function `gradient.addRepeatColorStop(pos, color)`

You use the resulting gradient as normal

```
const grad = RepeatingGradient(ctx, 0,0,0,10, 10);
grad.addRepeatColorStop(0, "#000");
grad.addRepeatColorStop(1, "#FFF");
ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
```

### Example use

Use mouse to draw using repeated gradient.

```js
function RepeatingGradient(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, repeats) {
    const dx = x2 - x1;
    const dy = y2 - y1;
    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(x1, y1, x1 + dx * repeats, y1 + dy * repeats);
    return Object.assign(gradient, {
        addRepeatColorStop(pos, color) {
            var i = 0;
            const step = 1 / repeats, offset = pos / repeats;
            while (i < repeats) { 
               const p = (i++) * step + offset;
               gradient.addColorStop(p > 1 ? 1 : p, color);
            }
        }
    });
}


const lineWidth = 20;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.height = innerHeight;
canvas.width = innerWidth;
ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
ctx.lineCap = "round";

const gradient = RepeatingGradient(ctx, 0, 0, 80, 80, 20);
gradient.addRepeatColorStop(0, "#F00");
gradient.addRepeatColorStop(0.25, "#FF0");
gradient.addRepeatColorStop(0.5, "#0F0");
gradient.addRepeatColorStop(0.75, "#FF0");
gradient.addRepeatColorStop(1, "#F00");
ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;

const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, ox: 0, oy: 0, button : false, updateFunc: undefined}
mouse.updateFunc = function draw() {
  if (mouse.button) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.ox, mouse.oy);
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();      
  }
}


function mouseEvents(e){
    const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouse.ox = mouse.x;
  mouse.oy = mouse.y;
    mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
  mouse.updateFunc && mouse.updateFunc();
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
Click drag mouse to draw.
```

### Notes

- The repeat is not infinite. You need to ensure that you cover all of the area you want painted.
- Repeats will reduce performance by a small amount depending on the number of repeats.
- Gradients use FLOATS (32 bit floating point) not DOUBLES (64 bit floating point). Adding too many repeats and you will start to get some artifacts (not all repeats are identical, some stops may be out of order). Try to keep the number of repeats to the minimum needed to fit the render area. (FLOAT is the upper size, low end devices may only support lower than 32bit precision floating point)
- If rounding errors start to effect the quality, try adding repeat stop ends slightly off 0 and 1

eg

```
gradient.addRepeatColorStop(0.01, "#F00");  // slightly above
gradient.addRepeatColorStop(0.99, "#F0F");  // slightly below
```

- For the best results try to have the first and last position in the repeat match each other.

eg

```
gradient.addRepeatColorStop(0,   "#F00");  // start
gradient.addRepeatColorStop(0.5, "#0F0");  // mid
gradient.addRepeatColorStop(1,   "#F00");  // Match start
```

### Using `pattern` to repeat gradients

The next method uses a pattern. Warning calling this function too often can result in a out of memory exception (gecko)

### The function

```
function RepeatingLinearGradient(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    const dx = x2 - x1;
    const dy = y2 - y1;
    const length = (dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 0.5 | 0;
    const can = document.createElement("canvas"); // support for OffscreenCanvas() limited
    can.width = length;
    can.height = 1;
    const ctxP = can.getContext("2d");
    const nx = dx / length;
    const ny = dy / length;
    const matrix =  new DOMMatrixReadOnly([nx, ny, -ny, nx ,x1, y1]);
    const gradient = ctxP.createLinearGradient(0, 0, length, 0);
    var dirty = true;
    function update() {
        ctxP.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctxP.fillRect(0,0,length, 1);
        var pattern;
        Object.assign(pattern = ctxP.createPattern(can, "repeat"), {
            addColorStop(pos, color) {
                gradient.addColorStop(pos, color);
                return update();
            }
        });
        pattern.setTransform(matrix);
        return pattern;
    }
    return update();
}
```

The function creates an off screen canvas and renders an axis align gradient to it. Each time you add a color stop a new pattern is created and returned.

To align the pattern with the desired gradient the patterns transform is set to match the gradients orientation.

### Usage

Similar to a normal gradient but returns a pattern. Arguments are two coordinate pairs  `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`

**IMPORTANT** As patterns are not live you must reassign the gradient every time you make a change (eg add color stop)

```
var gradient = RepeatingLinearGradient(0, 0, 80, 80);

/* MUST!!! reassign */
gradient = gradient.addColorStop(0, "#000"); // MUST!!! reassign
gradient = gradient.addColorStop(1, "#FFF"); // MUST!!! reassign

ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;
```

### Example

Use mouse to draw

```js
function RepeatingGradient(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    const dx = x2 - x1;
    const dy = y2 - y1;
    const length = (dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 0.5 | 0;
    const can = document.createElement("canvas");
    can.width = length;
    can.height = 1;
    const ctxP = can.getContext("2d");
    const nx = dx / length;
    const ny = dy / length;
    const matrix =  new DOMMatrixReadOnly([nx, ny, -ny, nx ,x1, y1]);
    const gradient = ctxP.createLinearGradient(0, 0, length, 0);
    var dirty = true;
    function update() {
        ctxP.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctxP.fillRect(0,0,length, 1);
        var pattern;
        Object.assign(pattern = ctxP.createPattern(can, "repeat"), {
            addColorStop(pos, color) {
                gradient.addColorStop(pos, color);
                return update();
            }
        });
        pattern.setTransform(matrix);
        return pattern;
    }
    return update();
}

const lineWidth = 20;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.height = innerHeight;
canvas.width = innerWidth;
ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
ctx.lineCap = "round";

var gradient = RepeatingGradient(0, 0, 40, 20);
gradient = gradient.addColorStop(0, "#F00");
gradient = gradient.addColorStop(0.25, "#FF0");
gradient = gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "#0F0");
gradient = gradient.addColorStop(0.75, "#FF0");
gradient = gradient.addColorStop(1, "#F00");
ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;

const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, ox: 0, oy: 0, button : false, updateFunc: undefined}
mouse.updateFunc = function draw() {
  if (mouse.button) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.ox, mouse.oy);
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();      
  }
}


function mouseEvents(e){
  const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouse.ox = mouse.x;
  mouse.oy = mouse.y;
  mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
  mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
  mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
  mouse.updateFunc && mouse.updateFunc();
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
Click drag mouse to draw.
```

### Notes

- Does not suffer the same floating point issues as the first method.
- Is slower when creating patterns and uses more memory.
- Can throw memory error if creating too often or adding stops too often.
- Repeats are infinite, You can not limit the number of repeats.
- Uses `DOMMatrixReadOnly` this may not be supported by all browsers.